# "woocommerce_can_reduce_order_stock" filter is not working on backend

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, backend, hook-woocommerce, orders

I have a custom order status called 'quote', and I have added the following code to try and prevent stock levels being decremented for orders with this status.

```php
function bw_do_not_reduce_quote_stock( $reduce_stock, $order ) {
    if ( $order->has_status( 'quote' ) ) {
        $reduce_stock = false;
    }
    return $reduce_stock;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_can_reduce_order_stock', 'bw_do_not_reduce_quote_stock', 10, 2 );
```

This works for orders placed on the front-end website. But if the admin adds or edits an order on the backend, the stock is decremented.

Is there an alternative hook for the backend? Or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to your current code, add the `woocommerce_prevent_adjust_line_item_product_stock` filter hook

```php
/**
 * Prevent adjust line item
 * 
 * @param $prevent
 * @param $item
 * @param $quantity
 */
function filter_woocommerce_prevent_adjust_line_item_product_stock ( $prevent, $item, $quantity ) {
    // Get order
    $order = $item->get_order();
    
    if ( $order->has_status( 'quote' ) ) {
        $prevent = true;
    }

    return $prevent;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_prevent_adjust_line_item_product_stock', 'filter_woocommerce_prevent_adjust_line_item_product_stock', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately it's not working for me though. For example, if I change an order status from 'cancelled' to 'quote', the stock still gets decremented.

Could this be because it is checking the old order status (cancelled) instead of the new status (quote)?

I've tried different hook priorities instead of 10 (e.g. 1 and 20) but the result is still the same.

Comment: that is indeed the reason, you could try it with has_status "cancelled" and then you will see that it does have its effect. Since the order already has the status in the frontend, it is assumed that this also applies in the backend part.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much for your help. For my workflow I have been able to just add 'cancelled' to the list of statuses: `$order->has_status ( array ('quote', 'cancelled') )` Now it works perfectly